# How To Fail the 'war' build from within _Events.groovy?

Tags: grails, war

I want to fail the build within my eventListener closure in `_Events.groovy` under certain circumstances.

I've attempted two approaches:

1. Throw a `RuntimeException()`
2. call `ant.fail('failing the build')`

I get the following output in the console for both:

```
    | Building WAR file.....
    running event listener code...
    [ERROR] Invalid environment argument of: 'tingaeuaeou', must be either 'testing', 'package', 'production' or 'native'
    | Error Exception occurred trigger event [CreateWarStart]: Sencha SDK optimization failed. (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
    | Done creating WAR target/product-selector-0.1.war
    grails>
```

Here is my code I've written to attempt to fail the build:

```
            ...
    ant.exec(outputproperty: "cmdOut", executable: 'sencha',
            dir: "$stagingDir", failOnError: true) {
        arg(value: 'app')
        arg(value: 'build')
        arg(value: "-e $senchaEnvironment")
    }

    def commandOutput = ant.project.properties.cmdOut

    println "${commandOutput}"

    if(commandOutput.contains('ERROR')){
        ant.fail(message:"Sencha SDK optimization failed.",status:1)
    }
            ...
```

The problem is that the war script keeps on running, generating a war file that will be broken, and I don't think my build process will report an exception happened; my continuous integration build will report a false success!

Any ideas?